# null exception returned from wcf method

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services, ria

I am using a silverlight application with RIA domain services. 
In that domain service I exposed a SOAP endpoint so that I can invoke domain service methods over SOAP. I did something like below in the web.config file.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <domainServices>
    <endpoints>
      <add name="soap" type="Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainService.Hosting.SoapEndpointFactory, Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainService.Hosting" />
    </endpoints>
  </domainServices>
<system.serviceModel>
```

Everything works well. When I launch my services from visual studio on my local ASP.net server I can get proper exceptions returned to my client.But when I host this domain service in IIS using the same web.config file I am getting back null exceptions.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Setting customErrors mode=false under in web.config file did the trick.